# R : approximation of probability

Tags: r, probability, approximation

Let X and Y be two independent random variables with density functions f_x(x) = x*exp(0.5*x^2)  where  x>0 and f_y(y) = 0.5 with y in [-1,1] .

I'm trying to approximate the probability P(Z>1) where Z =X+Y ; 
here is my R code :

```
u <-runif(10000, min=0, max=1000000); 
v<-runif(10000, min=-1, max=1);
f<-function(x){x*exp(-0.5*x^2)} ; 
g<-function(x){1/2} ; 
for ( i in 1:10000) {
I[i] = integrate ( f ,lower = 0 , upper = u[i]) ; 
J[i] = integrate ( g, lower =-1 , upper = v[i]) ; 
}
mean( (I+J)>1 ) ;
```

I'm getting this error :

```
Error in integrate(g, lower = -1, upper = v[i]) : 
  evaluation of function gave a result of wrong length
In addition: Warning message:
In I[i] = integrate(f, lower = 0, upper = u[i]) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Comment: [This](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/integrate-error-evaluation-of-function-gave-a-result-of-wrong-length-td4391036.html) might be helpful.

Comment: is the negative sign in the exp a typo? Since you mention in the description that that your density function is : f_x(x) = x*exp(0.5*x^2)

Comment: Maybe the description is wrong, I guess

Comment: Do you realize that the returned value from `integrate` is not a number but rather a list with named elements????

Comment: @mra68 There are (at least) two problems with the code above. A) the result from `integrate` will not be numeric so you cannot add it to anything, and B) both of you are failing to read the help page where it clearly states the requirements of a function passed to `integrate`. My (now reversed) downvote of your answer is because I find it unhelpful to accuse software of having bugs simply because you do not know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `g <- function(x){1/2}` by `g <- Vectorize(function(x){1/2} )` and `integrate(...)` by `integrate(...)$value`:

```
u <-runif(10000, min=0, max=1000000)
v<-runif(10000, min=-1, max=1)
f<-function(x){x*exp(-0.5*x^2)} 
g<-Vectorize(function(x){1/2 + 1e-12*x})

I <- rep(NA,10000)
J <- rep(NA,10000)

for ( i in 1:10000) {
  I[i] = integrate ( f ,lower = 0 , upper = u[i])$value
  J[i] = integrate ( g , lower =-1 , upper = v[i])$value 
}
mean( (I+J)>1 )
```

.

```
> mean( (I+J)>1 ) 
[1] 0.0048
>
```

Comment: That's not a bug in `integrate`. You gave it a function that only returns a single element. Read the help page.

Comment: This would also have succeeded and is probably more efficient: `g<-function(x){rep(1/2, times=length(x))}`